# facebook ssl content folder

Tags: facebook, ssl

I am going to set up secure hosting through my hosting company for a facebook app, I am wondering if it is possible to host multiple apps under one domain, one unique IP and one SSL certificate because multiple IPs and certificates cost more money and a wild card certificate is not an option.

Also let's say the content for app is under http://www.site.com/content/app1
when the SSL is added can the content be still under the same folder and accessed via
https://www.site.com/content/app1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem.  Just put them into separate subfolders on your server.  When you setup your app just set the URL's to the subfolders.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What about the secure and non secure version of the same app? Can they be share the same folder and just differ on facebook setting by the url? IE :
canvas url : http://www.domain.com/content/app1/
secure canvas url: https://www.domain.com/content/app1/

Comment: Code can be exactly the same.  Works just like a web page.